# How to invoke a NoAutomaticTrigger function in local development?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have some functions that I like to manually execute from time to time. I do not want them to be Timer Triggered.

I figured I can use `[NoAutomaticTrigger]` for these functions and they can be executed from the Azure Portal.

How can I execute them for testing .etc. during local development when running under `func.exe`?

(I know I can use an `[HttpTrigger]` but I prefer not to expose it to outside (even with a secure function authorization key) if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Disable function attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#c-class-libraries)?

Decorate the function with `[Disable("IsFunctionDisabledSetting")]`
This will cause the function to be disabled an any environment where an application setting `IsFunctionDisabledSetting=true`.

In your production configuration add an application setting of `IsFunctionDisabledSetting=true`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a RunOnStartup

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = 1)])
```

But I personally prefer to have a queueTrigger and then just insert a message in the queue for the function to run.

Comment: yea.. but this requires code change from NoAutomaticTrigger to TimerTrigger. Which means I could forget to change it back when deploying to production and it can start running there. Hoping there's some api in func.exe? similar to how azure portal execute these without a trigger change?

Comment: You can use a #if DEBUG / #else / #endif or alternatively an environment variable.